# Access to files on a server (asp.net, webmatrix)

Tags: asp.net, file

I want to read a *.txt file and edit this file. I use Webmatrix and it works on my computer. But after publishing it to a server  (Web deploy) it doesn't work anymore.

```
string transmission;
string path;
path = "E:\\Documents\\My Web Sites\\Trackercontrol v2\\backup.txt";

public int insert()
{
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path)) 
    {
        while ((transmission = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
        {
            // etc.
        }
    }
}
```

I published this, adjusted the path to the .txt file, but the try/cath method told me that the access to the path is denied. I think reading out the file isnt the problem but editing or clearing the file makes this problem.

How can I fix this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You gave the path of your local drive, which may be or sure does not exist on the server. First upload the file on the server and then read it. You can get the correct path as

```
 string path;
 path = Server.MapPath("~/filename.txt"); // Considered file is placed at Root of your site
```

Comment: I changed the path to the location of the file on the server

Comment: @user1641721 then what happened ?

Comment: the access to the file was denied^^

Comment: I'm not sure. On my local Computer I do have the rights. How can I change that? In Webmatrix or is it a server thing?

Comment: run visual studio as administrator if you are using win 7 or 8

Answer (score 0):

Check what account is the application pool running under?
Make sure that this account has read/write access to the file in concern.

Also, it would be a good idea to use

```
var path = Server.MapPath(relativePathToFile);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I try to use the relative Path to File. I am very new to this subject. But can I give the read/write access to the account in webmatrix, or must I do this in the server adjustments?

Comment: This would have to be a server adjustment. I don't think web matrix can publish permissions

Comment: Okay thank you, I talk to the server admin for this issue.

Why is it better to use ur idea for the path? do I need to include anything? i get an error using 
var path = Server.MapPath("backup.txt");

Comment: Error: The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context

Comment: A relative path is a lot easier to maintain. Changing the path in code everytime before you deploy is very error prone. If you must use a fixed path, it should come from configuration. Is this code not in an aspx.cs? `Server` is the property of the `Page` class.

Comment: okay that makes sense. but using the realtive path wither server.mappath returns the error: "The name 'Server' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: `Server` exists in a `Page`. Where is your code? Not being called from a `Page`?

Comment: I have a default.cshtml page (start page). i didnt want to include all the code in the cshtml file. so I created some *.cs files with the important code in them. the different files include different classes and one main file which creates all the classes

Comment: `Server` in a property of the asp.net `Page`. Not available in your own class. In your case a configuration file would work best.

Comment: thanks for your help! do you mean the web.config file? how does this work, or which are the key words so that I can google it?